# std::regex_error at memory location

Tags: c++, regex

I have a regex as:

```
std::regex regexp(
        R"(\$\ part,\ model.*[\n\r]([-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+[Ee]?[-+]?[0-9]*),([-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+[Ee]?[-+]?[0-9]*))",std::regex::extended);
```

The code compiles, but I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x748F49C2 in regex.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x00EFEE30.
```

Comment: I suggest you remove `std::regex::extended`, use the default ECMAScript flavor.

Comment: But my string has multiple lines.  a lot of "\n".

Comment: Regex flavor has nothing to do with the multiline input. Use the default one.

Comment: If you catch the exception, you will see `regex_error(error_escape): The expression contained an invalid escaped character, or a trailing escape.`

Comment: [`externded` syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) only allows certain special characters to be escaped by a backslash, not any arbitrary character. In particular, space is not a special character, and `\ ` is invalid in extended syntax. So are `\n` and `\r` it seems; those characters should be represented by themselves (which would be tricky in a raw string literal). All told, you probably don't want `extended`; you are probably looking for `multiline` option.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `multiline` is not necessary here, there are no `^` and `$` anchors in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the regex spec, the effect of escaping a space (which is not a special character) is undefined:

> **[9.4.2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_02) ERE Ordinary Characters**
>
> ... The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( `\` ) is undefined, except in the context of a bracket expression ...

Apparently in the MSVC implementation, `std::regex_error` gets thrown.

After fixing the escaping the regex compiles.

```
try {
    std::regex regexp(
        R"(\$ part, model.*[\n\r]([-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+[Ee]?[-+]?[0-9]*),([-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+[Ee]?[-+]?[0-9]*))", std::regex::extended);
}
catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```